# ssh private key works for root, but not for normal user

Tags: linux, putty, openssh

i have a linux (ubuntu 12) server, and a windows desktop.

i am trying to connect via ssh and private key

the server has these files

```
rw------- root.root /root/.ssh
rw------- root.root /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

rw------- user2.user2 /home/user2/.ssh
rw------- user2.user2 /home/user2/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

(i.e. chmod 600 for both .ssh directory AND the auth-key file)

The contents of "authorized_keys" is a copy for both root and user2. Only ownership is different.

When trying to connect from the desktop:

```
ssh -i mykey root@myhost.org   -- works, meaning the key is OK.
ssh -i mykey user2@myhost.org   -- doesn't work, for the same "mykey" file!
```

(Priv key fail, but password login works anyway, so it's not about server not accepting this user at all)

**What could possibly be different between the root and user2?**

(I tried also plink, putty's version for "ssh'ing", with PPK file - same results, so it's not a bug in ssh :) i think. )

Edit:

The specific error with ssh:

The authenticity of host '[myhost.org]:22 ([1.7.1.2]:22)' can't be established

Plink: "Server refused our key"

(ip/port/host in this msg are fake)

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377009/ssh-authorized-keys-not-working-properly the .ssh directory needs to have 700 permissions.

Comment: Thank you, that was correct. it solved my problem, but I still wonder then why there's a difference between root and "user2", and how comes I never encountered the need for 700 in the past decade!

Comment: I suppose that root has all permissions implicitly.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: could please make your comment an answer, so that the question doesn't remain unanswered?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Ok, Done.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, CristianCiupitu - done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per question [~/.ssh/authorized_keys not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6377009/850848), the `.ssh` directory needs to have 700 permissions.

The reason, it works for root even without the permissions set properly, is that root has implicit permissions for everything.

Comment: It's always weird when you're connect as a non-root user and you see that there's files you can't write into ^^